# flutter doctor: ERROR: Could not connect to lockdownd, error code -21

Tags: macos, terminal, visual-studio-code, flutter

I've got this error message when I try to run "flutter run" in the terminal.
Who knows how to fix this?

[image: Error terminal message]

Answer (score 9):

I fixed it.
It is because my iPad was connected to my computer.. DUUH!
When I disconnected my iPad the "flutter run" worked perfect!

Comment: For the record, identical stuff just happened to me too. I still don't get why the iPad sabotaged everything, though.

Comment: Error code -17 was because the iPhone device was connected.